# Spring boot authorizeHttpRequests requestMatchers cannot permit signup and login api url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am trying to whitelist "/api/auth/user-register", "/api/auth/login" urls to pass without any authentication. But my application is showing unauthorized handler to add basic authentication in signup and login request mappings. I use Spring Boot version 3.0.0.

Here is my SeciurityFilterChain code. I use basic authentication for requests.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/api/auth/user-register", "/api/auth/login").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/user/album/**", "/api/user/track/**", "/api/user/comment/**").hasAnyAuthority(UserLoginRole.USER.value())
            .requestMatchers("/api/test/all/**").hasAnyAuthority(UserLoginRole.SUPER_ADMIN.value())
            .requestMatchers("/api/user/comment/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .requestMatchers("/api/admin/comment/**").hasAnyAuthority(UserLoginRole.ADMIN.value())
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );

    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    http.formLogin().disable();
    http.httpBasic().realmName(REALM).authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint());
    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    //http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}
```

Result in postman
[image]

I tried authorized http requests manual in Spring docs.

Comment: Could you add the full confiugration class (including the class annotions etc.) and the resulting controller that will be executed. Looks like you don't have an `@Configuration` on there which makes it appear to be not applied.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `@Configuration`:

```
@Configuration
public class Security {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        
         http
          .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/Say_goodbey").permitAll();
         
        return http.build();
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using your code without using your roles and authorities methods and it works fine (I just changed the name of the authentication endpoint to /auth)

```
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    protected  AuthFilter authFilter(){
        return  new AuthFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/user/album/**", "/api/user/track/**", "/api/user/comment/**").hasAnyAuthority("UserLoginRole.USER.value()")
                        .requestMatchers("/api/test/all/**").hasAnyAuthority("UserLoginRole.SUPER_ADMIN.value()")
                        .requestMatchers("/api/user/comment/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/api/admin/comment/**").hasAnyAuthority("UserLoginRole.ADMIN.value()")
                        .requestMatchers("/users","/users/**").hasRole("USER")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )

                .addFilterBefore(authFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);



        return http.build();
    }
```

Please add the whole config class and ensure that you added `@Configuration` and `@EnableSecurity` annotations.